# C++ Function Template, Int Parameter Question

Tags: c++, templates, function, specialization

I was curious why this doesn't work:

```
const int ASSIGN_LEFT = 1;
const int ASSIGN_RIGHT = 2;

template <int AssignDirection>
void map( int& value1, int& value2 );

template<>
void map<ASSIGN_LEFT>( int& value1, int& value2 )
{  value1 = value2; }

template<>
void map<ASSIGN_RIGHT>( int& value1, int& value2 )
{  value2 = value1; }
```

When I try to use this function, it calls whichever template specialization I defined first.  So, `map<ASSIGN_RIGHT>` will call `map<ASSIGN_LEFT>` in the code above, unless I flip the order of the specialization, then it will always call `map<ASSIGN_RIGHT>`.

```
int main()
{
   int dog = 3;
   int cat = 4;

   map<ASSIGN_RIGHT>( dog, cat );
   std::cout << "dog= " << dog << ", cat= " << cat << std::endl;
}
```

Output is

```
dog= 4, cat= 4
```

The idea of this is so I don't have to write two routines to input/output data from a structure.

Auxiliary question -- I'd like to make the "int"s above a template parameter, but obviously you cannot do a partial specialization.  Would love to find a way around that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show how exactly you call that function?

Comment: Hm, the above works fine for me on VC8 and VC10.

Comment: @Georg:  Hmmm.  I don't know what I was doing when it "didn't work" in VC10... I tried it again with the OP's repro and it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following definitely works.  It also works around the fact that you can't partially specialize a function template by having the function template delegate to a specialized class template:

```
enum AssignDirection { AssignLeft, AssignRight };

template <typename T, AssignDirection D> 
struct map_impl;

template <typename T>
struct map_impl<T, AssignLeft>
{
    static void map(T& x, T& y) { x = y; }
};

template <typename T>
struct map_impl<T, AssignRight>
{
    static void map(T& x, T& y) { y = x; }
};

// Only template parameter D needs an explicit argument.  T can be deduced.
template <AssignDirection D, typename T>
void map(T& x, T& y)
{
    return map_impl<T, D>::map(x, y);
}
```